# Why isn't the ready state changing to 4?

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I made a simple form and on clicking submit it goes to AJAX and after processing it is sent to the servlet. I am not printing the servlet's response and just showing an alert, but its not working. Please, any solutions.
JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            function fn1()
            {
                x.onreadystatechange = fn2();

                x.open("GET","servlet1",true);
                x.send();

            }

            function fn2()
            {
                alert("happy");
                if(x.readyState==4)
                {
                    alert("happyness");
                }
            }


        </script>
```

Servlet:

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    out.print("hello");
}
```

Web-xml:

```
<servlet>
<description>This is the description of my J2EE component</description>
<display-name>This is the display name of my J2EE component</display-name>
<servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>ajaxeg2.servlet1</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>servlet1</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>/servlet1</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what is your servlet class? is it "servlet1" with small "s"?

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS 
                `

```
            var x = new XMLHttpRequest();
            x.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if(x.readyState == 4 && x.status == 200){
                alert("happyness");
            }
            };

            x.open("GET","servlet1",true);
            x.send();
```

you have call fn1() once to make ajax call and out.print will not work because its an ajax request so page is not reloading.

`